# How to call a different constructor in the ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, dependency-injection

In my ViewModel there are two different constructors:

```
    public ViewModel()
    {

    }
    public ViewModel(View View)
    {
        if (View!=null)
        {
        }
    }
```

I am using a `RelayCommand` and in the command binding I want to call the second constructor on button click. How can I call the second constructor and how do I pass the view in ViewModel.

Comment: Your ViewModel violates the MVVM pattern. The ViewModel isn't supposed to have **any** knowledge about a concrete View implementation. Second, what you are looking is Dependency Injection

Comment: Yes I am looking dependency injection. and pass the View in viewModel

Comment: Why exactly do you need the View?

Comment: I want to pass view into viewmodel.because from shelll i am creating viewmodel object and in viewmodel constructor i am doing this initialization  _view.DataContext = this; parentWindow = new ApplicationWindow("Title") { WindowContent = _view, IsResizable = false }; so i need the view by which i am assigning it to parentwindow